# Angular 4 hide/show using ng-container

Tags: angular, angular-template

Having an issue showing and hiding list items using ng-container. When I select a list item to show sub item lists it returns all sub item lists and not just the selected one.

```
List1 (Selected)
-item1
-item2

List2 (not selected but still showing items when List1 is selected and vice versa)
-item1
-item2
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side-nav" *ngFor="let sideNavMenuItem of sideNavMenuItems;">

    <ng-container>
      <li *ngIf="sideNavMenuItem.subMenu">
        <a id="link" routerLink="{{ sideNavMenuItem.url }}">

          <i class="menu-icon fa {{ sideNavMenuItem.menuIcon }}" aria-hidden="true">
          </i> <span class="menu-name" (click)="toggle()" id="bt">{{ sideNavMenuItem.menuName }}</span>

          <ul *ngFor="let subMenu of sideNavMenuItem.subMenu">
            <li *ngIf="show"><a routerLink="{{ subMenu.url }}">{{ subMenu.menuName}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </a>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

**Component**

```
toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change show to array of Boolean instead of one value to all objects.
and add index to the *ngFor:

```
<ul class="side-nav" *ngFor="let sideNavMenuItem of sideNavMenuItems; let i = index">
```

on the click event, add the index of the object:

```
<span class="menu-name" (click)="toggle(i)" id="bt">{{ sideNavMenuItem.menuName }}</span>
```

and change the toggle function to:

```
toggle(index) {
  this.show[index] = !this.show[index];
}
```

and last thing in the *ngIf add the index in the show array

```
<li *ngIf="show[i]">
  <a routerLink="{{ subMenu.url }}">{{ subMenu.menuName}}</a>
</li>
```